# Does the power "Elfsight" help notice secret doors?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

While the short description in the powers list mentions noticing secret doors, the long description does not.

The short description for the power "Elfsight" is as follows:
"Gain low-light vision, +2 bonus on Perception checks, and notice secret doors."

However, the full description is as follows:
"You gain low-light vision (as an elf) for the duration of the power, as well as a +2 bonus on vision-based Perception checks.
If elfsight is used in conjunction with my light, the cone of light extends out to 80 feet instead of 40 feet."

I assume that in this case I should defer to the long description. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The long description applies, the secret door rule was removed for Pathfinder, it formerly existed in D&D 3.5.

They seem to have forgotten to remove the line on the short description.

Answer (score -2):

The Perception skill is used for spotting secret doors, I believe the short description's implication is that the bonus to Perception will help in that regard. I would use the long description as that's the one likely copied from the handbook.

For the interest's sake, the average Perception DC for standard hidden doors is 20.

Comment: Perception also helps finding all sorts of other things, too. Why would the short description single out secret doors if the explanation was that simple? To be clear, both descriptions are copied word-for-word from different parts of the same book. I'm not referencing from the SRD.